# Dump базы MySQL огромного размера

Tags: mysql, база-данных, dump

Проблема:
Делая дамп бд, скажем, 3 гигов, mysql блокирует на чтение и запись всю бд.

Т.е. юзеры, которые коннектятся и хотят получить инфу, просто ждут минут 5.

Подскажите, как правильно организовать дамп бд, чтобы можно было и записывать в неё и читать с неё?

Спасибо.

Comment: Т.е. юзеры, которые коннектятся и хотят получить инфу, просто ждут минут 5.
ШАПИТО)

Comment: @evm, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вы дамп делаете с помощью mysqldump?

`--lock-tables=false` или `--skip-add-locks` пробовали?

**Обновление**

Почему бы не поискать?

[`--lock-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) и там же [`--skip-add-locks`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-locks)

Comment: Да, с помощью mysqldump, и эти конфиги не пробовал, а что они делают?

Comment: @evm почему бы не поискать?

[`--lock-tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) и там же [`--skip-add-locks`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-locks)

Comment: А какие подводные камни у этих конфигов?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого обычно делают ещё один сервер с мускулем и настраивают репликацию. Это решает большинство проблем.